# JQuery check if localStorage is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have some text on the page in a div called clicker, when I click on this div I want to either set the localStorage value to 1 if it is 0 or 0 if it is 1.

I have the below in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7X4z/).
It seems to be toggling the value but isn't quite right eg if I click on the text 'click' then I can see it makes aaa=1 but if i run the fiddle again the class isn't applied?  What is the best way to do this?

JS

```
        $(function(){
            $('#clicker').click(function() {
                if (localStorage['aaa'] == "1") {
                    $(this).addClass('off');
                    localStorage.setItem("aaa", 0);
                }
                else {
                    $(this).removeClass('off');
                    localStorage.setItem("aaa", 1);
                }
            });

            if (localStorage['aaa'] == "1") {
                $('#play').addClass('off');
            }
        });
```

HTML

```
        <div id="clicker">click</div>
```

CSS

```
        .off {
            color: #fff;
            background: grey;
        }
```

Comment: Where is the `#play` element in your fiddle?

Comment: On reload should the `off` class be applied as it was before the page was unloaded (at which point the `localStorage` property will have been set to the opposite value) or according to the new value of the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using the wrong selector id

```
if (localStorage['aaa'] == "1") {
    //$('#play').addClass('off');
    $('#clicker').addClass('off');
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/q7X4z/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I might be be barking up the wrong tree, but I guess you expect something like a '**Cross-domain localStorage**'.
If you are expecting that your `localStorage['aaa']` is accessible from both your site and jsfiddle, you need to manage the limitation of the **same-origin policy** .

You might want to read this article by Nicholas C. Zakas:
Learning from XAuth: Cross-domain localStorage
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/